# Remove particular category name in default Layered Navigation in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I want to remove only one category name under Layered Navigation so how to proceed this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the "Anchor" option in

Product->Categories->[Your category name]->Display

Setting